# D3 v4 collapsible tree using the d3 link generator

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, graph, tree

I am trying the implementation of the **collapsible tree** in d3 v4. I was plying with [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/43a860bc0024792f8803bba8ca0d5ecd) and realized, it is using a custom function to create the link shape

```
// Creates a curved (diagonal) path from parent to the child nodes
function diagonal(s, d) {

    path = `M ${s.y} ${s.x}
            C ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${s.x},
            ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${d.x},
            ${d.y} ${d.x}`

    return path
}
```

Since *d3 v 4.9* there is a built-in [link generator](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#linkHorizontal) and I wonder how can it be used in this example.

I have troubles understanding following calls

```
// Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .attr('d', function(d){
    var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0}
    return diagonal(o, o)
});

....

// Remove any exiting links
var linkExit = link.exit().transition()
  .duration(duration)
  .attr('d', function(d) {
    var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y}
    return diagonal(o, o)
})
.remove();
```

I understand, that this is creating a curved line from point(x,y) to point (x,y) - so basically from and to the same point ?

Furthermore, I tried to update

```
// Transition back to the parent element position
linkUpdate.transition()
  .duration(duration)
  .attr('d', function(d){ return diagonal(d, d.parent) });
```

with following code

<del>// Transition back to the parent element position
     linkUpdate.transition()
     .duration(duration)
     .attr('d', d3.linkHorizontal(d, d.parent))


but I got *Uncaught ReferenceError: d is not defined*</del>

```
// Transition back to the parent element position
linkUpdate.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr('d', d3.linkHorizontal()
        .source(function (d) {return d.parent})
        .target(function (d) {return d})
    );
```

but I got lot of errors in the console

```
d3.v4.min.js:2 Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,NaNCNaN,NaN,…".
```

Could someone explain my mistake or point me to some working code ? Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I figured out most of the confusion from my original answer.

Creating the *"zero length path"* on link creation

```
var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .attr('d', function(d){
    var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0}
    return diagonal(o, o)
});
```

and on link removal

```
var linkExit = link.exit().transition()
  .duration(duration)
  .attr('d', function(d) {
    var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y}
    return diagonal(o, o)
  })
 .remove();
```

is used to create the animation, when the nodes, together with the related links slides-out/retrieves-back-in their parent nodes. The animation animates transformation of the path to/from their final shape from/to the *"null"* shape - thus the link starting and finishing at the same coordinates.

**The link generator** can be then used like this

```
// Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr('d', d3.linkHorizontal()
        .source(function(){ return [sourceNode.y0, sourceNode.x0]})
        .target(function(){ return [sourceNode.y0, sourceNode.x0]}));

 ...

// Transition back to the parent element position
linkUpdate.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr('d', d3.linkHorizontal()
        .source(function (d) {return [d.parent.y, d.parent.x]})
        .target(function (d) {return [d.y, d.x]})
    );

 ...

// Remove any exiting links
var linkExit = link.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr('d', d3.linkHorizontal()
        .source(function(){ return [sourceNode.y, sourceNode.x]})
        .target(function(){ return [sourceNode.y, sourceNode.x]}))
    .remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is too late but here is a great example of how to animate the path https://observablehq.com/@onoratod/animate-a-path-in-d3. Just build a path then animate it.

```
    const linkGen = d3.linkHorizontal();
    const paths = linksData.map(d => {
                        return { path: linkGen({target:...,source:...}), color: d.color }
                    })
 paths.map(path => {
                    var path = svg.append("path")
                        .attr("d", path.path)
                        .attr("fill", "none")
                        .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                        .attr("stroke", path.color);

                    const length = path.node().getTotalLength();

                    // This function will animate the path over and over again
                    // Animate the path by setting the initial offset and dasharray and then transition the offset to 0
                    path.attr("stroke-dasharray", length + " " + length)
                        .attr("stroke-dashoffset", length)
                        .transition()
                        .ease(d3.easeLinear)
                        .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0)
                        .duration(3000)
                })
```